# What time zone does a scheduled job use for Preferred Start Time

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

We have a scheduled job that runs on the 1st of each month with a Preferred Start Time of 1am. The job was scheduled using the Salesforce interface (Develop | Apex Classes | Schedule Apex). When it runs, it sets a month field for records based on the System date (`System.today();`). Occasionally, the month is set wrongly, and I suspect it's due to the date variable set to the System date.

If I set the job to run at 1am, logged in as my User (with a time-zone set to CDT), using the interface, what value would be returned by `System.today()`? Would the current CDT date be returned, or the GMT date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scheduled jobs run as "system", but I think there's still a user context, which means `Date.today()` or `System.today()` would be in CDT.

Update:

Just tested this and `DateTime.now()` returns GMT values.

Another update:

The docs say `Date.today()` returns the date in the current user's time zone. Based on the test below, the system knows who the user is, and it knows the user's time zone, so `Date.today()` would be the current date in the user's time zone. I confirmed this by setting my time zone to +10, and the system returned 2012-03-15 for the date.

```
// Brisbane +10 time zone
global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
  System.debug(DateTime.now()); // 2012-03-14 19:24:39
  System.debug(DateTime.now().formatLong()); // 3/15/2012 5:24:39 AM AEST
  System.debug(Date.today()); // 2012-03-15 00:00:00
  System.debug(UserInfo.getUserName()); // dev1@jeremyross.org
}
```

Comment: You're correct. I didn't think of this test earlier, but I tried setting my user to a time zone that would have tomorrow's date and ran `System.today();` in Execute Anonymous, and indeed it does use the current User's Time Zone when returning the date. It returned `2012-03-15 00:00:00`.

Answer (score 3):

From [the APEX dev guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm):

```
The System.Schedule method uses the user's timezone for the basis of all schedules.
```

Comment: That refers to when the job runs, not the semantics of date/time values inside the job.